# Is there a way to apply css web fonts in the woff file format in an explorer 8 environment?

Tags: css

I want to apply web fonts in Explorer 8. However, my woff file is not applied as web page font. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Should stop supporting ie8 - it is really out of date and a security risk for anyone that uses it

Comment: @Pete 
Oh, I see. However, the current development environment is an Explorer 8 environment. Thank you for answer.

Comment: You should upgrade your environment then - microsoft haven't released any patches for nearly 2 years and that means there are a lot of exploits that hackers will know about with that browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The woff file is not supported in Explorer 8 or earlier. To apply web font, you need to include eot file because it supports eot file only.